# ABRecordRef store value that is not visible to the user?

Tags: ios, addressbookui

I am working on an app that uses the iOS Address book.

I am wondering if there is a way to store a value of some kind in a ABRecordRef (so a contact card) that the user can't see. I would like to do that to use that value as a reference around my app.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddressBook` doesn't allow for storing custom metadata in the store itself for an `ABRecordRef`.  However, an `ABRecordRef` does have an [`ABRecordID` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABRecordGetRecordID) that you can use to correlate information that is useful to your own application.  You could stuff these IDs in CoreData, a property list, or even user defaults so that you can match your metadata up with a specific address book contact.